# Why can't I pass user input to this directive in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and I'm trying to figure out why the current code, which is supposed to get user input and pass it to the chart directive, is resulting in undefined when I call `console.log(foo);` inside that directive.

Markup:

```
     <div class="row" ng-controller="Controller">

        <input type="text" ng-model="key" >
        <div class="col-md-12" chart>
            <section data="{{key}}"></section>
        </div>

      </div>         
    </div>
```

App.js

```
(function(){
    var draw = angular.module('Draw', [])  
    draw.controller('Controller',function($scope) {
        $scope.key = 'aSampleKey';
     });

    draw.directive('chart', function(){

    function link(scope, element, attr){    
        var foo = scope.data;

        //why is this undefined? 
        console.log(foo);
    }

    return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {data: "="}
    };
}); 
})();
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you declare the value on the isolated scope, you need to pass it as an attribute to the directive:

```
<div class="col-md-12" chart data="key">
    <section></section>
</div>
```

Also if you want to pass the value as a string with `{{key}}`, you need to use the `@` symbol when isolating the scope:

```
<div class="col-md-12" chart data="{{key}}">
    <section></section>
</div>
```

and

```
return {
        link: link,
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {data: "@"}
    };
```